# Ionic tcp programming using socket.io issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, tcp

I need to develop an app in ionic that uses TCP connection in order to send and receive data. So there is a library socket.io, I used this library, but the problem is I want to communicate the app sends data from phone to an Arduino device. After a search I think this is not possible with socket.io because it should work in a browser at the client side.

Is there another library for TCP to send and receive data from phone to Arduino or vice versa?